# right permission for plugins in wordpress and debian 8

Tags: wordpress, debian, file-permissions, apache2.4

I don't know if my problem is reported but ...

I have a (latest i think) wordpress 4.3.1 installed on debian 8 (apache 2.4.10, php 5.6.14) and I configured apache/envvars file with umask 002.

When I create a new file from php script, this new file has the good right permissions for me : www-data and 664 (775 for directories) due to umask in apache.

But when I install a plugin from wordpress admin, all new files are this permissions : www-data (owner and group => normal) and 644 (755 for directories)!

I tried on another server in debian 7.x with the same wordpress installation and same apache configuration. The new plugin from admin installation has 664 / 775 right permissions.

I don't know what happened. Do you have an idea. I forget anything?
Thanks very much.

Momo

*Very sorry if subject has been treated :)*

**EDIT** : when I upload an image, the right permissions are good => www-data (owner and group), 664

gloups!

Comment: Did you talk with server technical team?

Comment: i'm server technical team :)
So I have totally access to this server
thanks

Comment: Hello, with fresh install of wp I don't have this problem !
Perhaps a wrong thing or bad installation... ouf I'm happy. thks to all !